# apache before glassfish - ajax not working if passed to url-rewritten subfolder

Tags: ajax, apache, jsf, jakarta-ee, reverse-proxy

I use apache as a reverse-proxy before glassfish  and when I am trying to proxy-pass to a rewritten subfolder instead of the main I get following problem.

All ajax calls aren't working anymore resulting in a `500 Internal Server Error`.

When I will proxy-pass to the **main folder** i get no problems.

**JSF - Rewriterules:**

Using http://ocpsoft.org/ rewrite solution to create the virtual url the apache shall proxy too:

```
`/foo/{fooViewParamValue} -> /sites/foo/foo.xhtml`
```

**Apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ProxyRequests Off

    <proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        # Deny from all 
        Allow from all
    </proxy>

    SetOutputFilter proxy-html 
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # map resources
    ProxyPass            /res/ http://localhost:2080/res/
    ProxyPassReverse     /res/ http://localhost:2080/res/
    # map subfolder
    ProxyPass            / http://localhost:2080/foo/fooViewParamValue/
    ProxyPassReverse     / http://localhost:2080/foo/fooViewParamValue/
    # map main folder - test
    #ProxyPass            / http://localhost:2080/
    #ProxyPassReverse     / http://localhost:2080/


    # map processed html elements
    ProxyHTMLLinks  a       href
    ProxyHTMLLinks  area        href
    ProxyHTMLLinks  link        href
    ProxyHTMLLinks  img     src longdesc usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks  object      classid codebase data usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks  q       cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks  blockquote  cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks  ins     cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks  del     cite
    ProxyHTMLLinks  form        action
    ProxyHTMLLinks  input       src usemap
    ProxyHTMLLinks  head        profile
    ProxyHTMLLinks  base        href
    ProxyHTMLLinks  script      src for

    # map processed html events
    ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
            onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
            onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
            onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On

    # main folder html 
    #ProxyHTMLURLMap  / /
    # subfolder html 
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /foo/fooViewParamValue/ /
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /foo/fooViewParamValue /
</VirtualHost>
```

**Observation:**

Sometimes it is enough to remove the content of the form action attribute (in firebug) to make it work, but sometimes the exception is looged in an endless loop:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton/>
</h:form>
<!-- final html -->
<form action="/sites/foo/foo.xhtml">
    <button/>
</form>
<!-- removing action content sometimes works -->
    <form action="">
    <button/>
</form>
```

**Exception that is logged:**

Sometimes once, sometimes in a loop:

```
Warnung: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115)
at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:252)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at package.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:48)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Edit1:**

I removed `//Rewrite` and mapped to the physical subfolder from apache and had no problems.
Since mapping works without using `ocp rewrite` without a problem. Rewrite itself must be the reason.

**Edit2:**

Moving back to predecessor `PrettyFaces` it works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `//Rewrite` forum I got the answer:

The form url was not mapped resulting in invalid url while passing the proxy.

The postback url of the form is `/sites/foo/foo.xhtml` and was unmapped.
 without view-parameters.

1. Map the form url using rewrite rule: `cb.addRule(Join.path("/foo/").to("/sites/foo/foo.xhtml")`
2. Add the `ProxyHTMLURLMap  /foo/ /` to apache proxy config

Rewritten on proxy this will result into form src `/`.
Empty could also be possible removing trailing slash from pattern.

**Curious:**It strangely worked with `pretty-faces` where this rule was also not mapped.